# Random blank space between navbar and bxslider

Tags: jquery, html, css, bxslider

I'm getting a weird spacing issue where the bottom of the navbar isn't lining up with my bxslider. It seems like theres roughly 15-30px that is getting pushed off but no matter what I do the spacing will never decrease. Any help would be greatly appreciated

The Html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Charity</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link href="lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script src="js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        mode: 'fade',
        speed: '3000',
        auto: false,
        autoControls: false
    });
  });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id='nav'>
  <ul class='navigation-left'>
    <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Events</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="navigation-right">
    <li><a href='#'>Full list of Charities</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- end of nav -->
<img src="images/main-logo.png" id="logo" />

<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="images/placeholder.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/placeholder.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/placeholder.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/placeholder.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

My css

```
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#nav {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #CCC;
    height: 66px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px #5E5E5E;
    position: relative;
}
.navigation-left li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: auto;
}
.bxslider{
    padding:0px;
}
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -175px;
}
.navigation-left {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
    margin-right: 200px
}
.navigation-right {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: 100px;
} 
#nav a {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0.3em #464646;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: century gothic;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #262626;
    opacity: 0.26;
}
#nav a:hover {
    opacity: 0.36;
}
```

The basic css from bxslider

```
/** RESET AND LAYOUT
===================================*/

.bx-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto 60px;
    padding: 0;
    *zoom: 1;
}

.bx-wrapper img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

/** THEME
===================================*/

.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
    border: solid #fff 5px;
    left: -5px;
    background: #fff;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -30px;
    width: 100%;
}

/* LOADER */

.bx-wrapper .bx-loading {
    min-height: 50px;
    background: url(images/bx_loader.gif) center center no-repeat #fff;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2000;
}

/* PAGER */

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #666;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager .bx-pager-item,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-controls-auto-item {
    display: inline-block;
    *zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a {
    background: #666;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    outline: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a.active {
    background: #000;
}

/* DIRECTION CONTROLS (NEXT / PREV) */

.bx-wrapper .bx-prev {
    left: 10px;
    background: url(images/controls.png) no-repeat 0 -32px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-next {
    right: 10px;
    background: url(images/controls.png) no-repeat -43px -32px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-prev:hover {
    background-position: 0 0;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-next:hover {
    background-position: -43px 0;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -16px;
    outline: 0;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a.disabled {
    display: none;
}

/* AUTO CONTROLS (START / STOP) */

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
    text-align: center;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 11px;
    outline: 0;
    background: url(images/controls.png) -86px -11px no-repeat;
    margin: 0 3px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start.active {
    background-position: -86px 0;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 9px;
    height: 11px;
    outline: 0;
    background: url(images/controls.png) -86px -44px no-repeat;
    margin: 0 3px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop.active {
    background-position: -86px -33px;
}

/* PAGER WITH AUTO-CONTROLS HYBRID LAYOUT */

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls.bx-has-controls-auto.bx-has-pager .bx-pager {
    text-align: left;
    width: 80%;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls.bx-has-controls-auto.bx-has-pager .bx-controls-auto {
    right: 0;
    width: 35px;
}

/* IMAGE CAPTIONS */

.bx-wrapper .bx-caption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #666\9;
    background: rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.75);
    width: 100%;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-caption span {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial;
    display: block;
    font-size: .85em;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a live demo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you haven't used any reset. So I would suggest you to use Erik Meyer's CSS Reset on the top of your CSS file like I have shown in this [JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SX9H2/) or for quick reset you can write the following line on the top of your CSS File:

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

After this, you need to remove the `border` property from `.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport` selector which is about 5px. So, your CSS for that would be like:

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
    left: -5px;
    background: #fff;
}
```

I removed `box-shadow` as well because there's no use of it if you don't want any space between your slider and navigation.

Hope this helps. :)